# Highlight cells which aren't formatted as 13 digit text...how?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I've found how to conditionally format cells that contain text rather than numbers, and that's actually how I found this site, but need to Conditional Format any cells in a column which ARE NOT 13digit text. All cells will be "numbers" but they need to be formatted as text.

I have a program which uses UPC's but they must be formatted as text, 13 digits long, and must have leading `0`'s.  I'm building a template and need to alert users when the UPC they've provided doesn't match the format the program desires as the program will simply disregard that line rather than giving an error.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the range that you wish to format BEFORE opening the Conditional Formatting dialog.

Open the Conditional Formatting dialog.

Select: New Rule.

Select: *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*.

Enter the formula into the box labeled, *Format values where this formula is true*.

This is the formula:

```
=(LEN(A1)<>13)*LEN(A1)
```

> NOTE: the reference to A1 should be changed to the first cell in your current selection.

Click on the Format button and select the formats you wish.

Confirm.